# Normalization...Which table does the Address field belong in?

Tags: database-normalization

I'm trying to understand how to apply the concept of normalization. I’m working with this example that I came across online.

**FIRST NORMAL FORM…**
[image]

**CONVERSION TO SECOND NORMAL FORM…**
[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

My question about this is, how would I know if `Address` belongs in the `Membership_Details_Table`. Doesn’t it seem like the following would be a better schema in case a member has multiple addresses?

```
**Table1**
MembershipID
Salutation
FullName

**Table2**
MembershipID
Address

**Table3**
MembershipID
BooksIssued
```

Comment: You're right... You should keep different entities in different table. So having a new table for address makes more sense.. As address would change more often than name.

Comment: Gaurang, that's what I was thinking. Also so you don't have to retype the other fields if the member has multiple addresses. It'd be redundant

Comment: have a different table for different entities and sub entities

Comment: This is too broad & not clear--an answer explaining what you need to know & what an answer is forms chapters of a book & a bespoke tutorial. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Time to follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design (including "normalization to higher NFs"). (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Ask just 1 specific ([so] non-duplicate) question about the 1st place you get stuck.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.

Comment: That "2NF" schema is not a decomposition of the "1NF" schema. Your source seems to be [this page](https://support.dbagenesis.com/knowledge-base/database-normalization/) which is a typically poor, wrong & useless presentation.

Comment: Philipxy, this is a theoretical question. Not something that you would be using to diagnose a problem. Therefore, you shouldn't need it in text.

Comment: @NickT All the reasons for code as text apply to any text as text. PS "2NF", "normalize (to higher NFs) (by lossless decomposition)" & "normalize to 2NF" have technical meanings, but unfortunately this post doesn't show understanding or application of them. (Dozens of published academic information modeling & DB design textbooks are online free in pdf. stanford.edu has a free online course.) PS You forgot to use @ (there is more than one non-poster commenter) so I didn't get notified but I happened to pass by.

Answer (score -1):

No.  The second method is just duplicating information about a particular member across two different tables.  That is sometimes useful, but not for normalization.

It is possible that different members might be at the same address:

Members

- MembershipID
- Salutation
- FullName
- AddressId

Addresses

- AddresssId
- Address

Note the difference:  The `addresses` table has its own id.

Or it is also possible that the addresses change over time.  That would suggest a type-2 table.  However, your data has no dates, so that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: With your method you would still have to have two records in the Members table if they have more than one address. Which suggests you would also have to type redundant data (FullName, Salutation). Just a thought

Comment: Normalization to higher NFs does not involve adding new columns. It replaces a table by others that have proper subsets of its columns.

Comment: @NickT . . . There is no evidence that there is more than one address for a member, but that is definitely another good point.